# java.io.NotSerializableException Change hasMany to ArrayList

Tags: grails, serialization, validation

```
class Author {

    String name

    ArrayList<Book> books = []

    static hasMany = [books: Book]

    static mapping = {
      books cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }

}
```

The error occurs when I try to save the object. "java.io.NotSerializableException". Any ideas? Do I need to implement Serializable in the class? If so, why?

Comment: Hi, I'm an SVNKit developer but I've never seen such an exception. I would state that maybe it's groovy problem (I'm not groovy specialist). As a first step I would recommend you to realize if the problem is really relaed to SVNKit or groovy, e.g. by an attempt to reproduce the problem in pure Java. If the problem is reproducible in Java, please create an issue at http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issues/SVNKIT

Comment: Just found out the problem is in Groovy - going to update this.

Comment: I attempted to add "implements Serializable" in the domain class with no luck.

Comment: I changed ArrayList<Book> books = [] to List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(). I now get "object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: project.Book"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
class Author {

    String name

    SortedSet books

    static hasMany = [books: Book]

    static mapping = {
      books cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }

}

   class Book implements Comparable {
      String title

      static belongsTo = [author: Author]

      int compareTo(obj) {
        title.compareTo(obj.title)
      }

   }
```